# css Positions are not same in mozilla and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, mozilla

I have used the below inline style for img tag. but the positions are different in mozilla and chrome.

```
element.style {   position: absolute;   top: 118px;   LEFT: 64px; }
```

In Mozilla image is displayed properly. But in chrome the images are scattered

why is it happening like this.? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for this issue.

Comment: I think this can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576624/problem-with-absolute-positioning-in-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 2):

used one div wrapper for position relative like that:-

```
  <div style="position:relative">
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 118px; LEFT: 64px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to use position absolute on an image within a fieldset. From here, change your right and top positioning to make it work for you in Firefox. (leave your original class in place for IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera)

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .classToApply{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
  }
}
```

This is a Firefox Hack that I'm told works for every version of Firefox. I'm using Firefox Version 33.0.2, so I can't confirm this works on older versions. I had the same problem on my site. It looked the same in IE, Opera, Safari, and Chrome. It was only in Firefox I noticed the positioning different. This works!